# Tensorflow local mutable mask

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to design a Tensorflow function that only works on a subset of the input tensor. Internally, I think the best way to accomplish this is to create a mask of bools indicating which entries of the tensor are "active" and which should be ignored.

I already have a numpy implementation that looks like this

```
def func( data, maxIterations ):

    ndata = len( data )
    ind   = numpy.arange( ndata )
    mask  = numpy.ones( (ndata,), dtype=tf.bool )

    for iteration in range( maxIterations ):

         # Determine which part of the input tensor is "active"
         # Note that the "for" loop will be vectorized in practice
         mask.fill(False)
         for point in data:
             if condition(point):
                mask[point] = True

         # Now do something with the active part of the tensor
         doSomething( data, mask )
```

Now I want to convert this to a Tensorflow implementation. The problem seems to be that I cannot figure out how I would create a mutable mask that would not be updated by the optimization routine. For instance, the `tf.ones` function seems to be creating a immutable array of ones. How would I make that mutable?

```
def func_tf( data, maxIterations ):

    ndata = tf.shape(data)[0]
    ind   = tf.range( ndata )
    mask  = tf.ones( (ndata,), dtype=bool )

    for iteration in range( maxIterations ):

         # Determine which part of the input tensor is "active"
         # Note that the "for" loop will be vectorized in practice
         tf.assign(mask, False)
         for point in data:
             if condition(point):
                mask[point] = True

         # Now do something with the active part of the tensor
         doSomething( data, mask )
```

I should add that creating the array as a numpy array and then wrapping with a `tf.Variable` seems terribly inefficient since it would have to transfer stuff from the CPU to the GPU.

Alternatively, if you have an alternative design pattern that you typically use for these types of problems, I would love to here it!

Comment: Have a look at the `tensorflow.where` function. It provides functionality similar to numpy's advanced indexing and should do the trick provided you can express `condition` in terms of tensorflow. Generally, thinking of tensorflow ops in terms of mutable/immutable objects is not a good idea IMAO.

Comment: Are suggesting that I don't use a mask at all?

Comment: I am suggesting to construct the mask via `tensorflow.where` (if that's possible). It would help to know what `condition` looks like to judge whether it's a viable alternative.

Comment: Hmm. I will think about it. I am trying to create an extensible function that I can use multiple times in the code, so I want to make sure that the API doesn't become unnecessarily complicated.